# Azure DevOps python feed error on pip install

Tags: python, pip, azure-devops

Established am Azure DevOps python feed and publised a python package, but can not install it in my pipeline.

**azure-pipelines.yml:**

```
- task: PipAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'Pip Authenticate'
  inputs:
    artifactFeeds: my_feed
    onlyAddExtraIndex: true
- script: pip install my-package==0.0.1234
```

**output:**

```
##[section]Starting: Pip Authenticate
==============================================================================
Task         : Python pip authenticate
Description  : Authentication task for the pip client used for installing Python distributions
Version      : 1.156.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/pip-authenticate
==============================================================================
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
Successfully added auth for 1 internal feeds and 0 external endpoint.
##[section]Finishing: Pip Authenticate

##[section]Starting: CmdLine
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.151.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
pip install my-package==0.0.1234
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/user/.../_work/_temp/029c4dab-3726-41d8-896a-ed539e6bc712.sh
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://build:****@pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../_packaging/.../pypi/simple
Collecting my-package==0.0.1234
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-package==0.0.1234 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for my-package==0.0.1234
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: CmdLine
```

**How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!**

Comment: package doesnt exist in that feed?

Comment: Yes, sure. It does exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure DevOps python feed error on pip install

First, you need double check if the version `0.0.1234` of that package in the feed.

Second, according to the error message, it seems you are using the `Python 2.7`, please try to update your Python to `3.6.x`.

Third, when you update python to 3.6.x, you still have the same issue, please try to upgrade pip to the latest version using:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Update:

Thanks for user2809176 sharing the detailed solution for his issue:

> **A python version used during a package creation should match the
>   version used during an installation.**
>
> E.g. if in /dist folder you have my-package-0.0.1234-py3-none-any.whl
>   you should install it with python version 3. Otherwise you will get
>   this error message.
>
> I guess my-package-0.0.1234-py2-none-any.whl will show the same error
>   if you try to install it with python 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have already tried to update versions - getting the same error

Comment: @user2809176, both update python version and pip version?

Comment: could you please update your answer to include additional info from my answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @user2809176, Of course. Thank you for your sharing. I have updated my answer :).

Answer (score 0):

A python version used during a package creation should match the version used during an installation.

E.g. if in `/dist` folder you have **my-package-0.0.1234-py3-none-any.whl** you should **install it with python version 3**. Otherwise you will get this error message.

I guess my-package-0.0.1234-py2-none-any.whl will show the same error if you try to install it with python 3.